# Как сделать так, чтобы сайт загруженный на GitHub Pages открывался не из корневого каталога репозитория, а из конкретной папки?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Есть репозиторий https://github.com/Meinerdi/meinerdi.github.io залитый на GitHub Pages.
Нужно сделать так что-бы сайт загружался именно из папки dist а не из корневого каталога: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: документацию изучали? Я за 2 минуты нашел например в мануале про директорию /docs, может дальше найдете как указать другую директорию https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/#publishing-your-github-pages-site-from-a-docs-folder-on-your-master-branch

Comment: судя по документации — никак. единственный вомзожный вариант исчерпывается каталогом `docs`.